# Type erasure in Java

Tags: java, collections, type-conversion, type-erasure

I had to process nested collections (for example, a map of lists or a map of maps) and that is the way I was going to handle it:

```
  public static String doSomething(Map<?, ? extends Collection<?>> map) {
     ...
  }

  public static String doSomething(Map<?, ? extends Map<?, ?>> map) {
     ...
  }
```

But I am told by the compiler that the above two methods have the same type erasure. I wonder why, since I have specified different type bounds.

Comment: Did you read up on type erasure? After applying it both methods will look like `public static String doSomething(Map map)`.

Comment: I have read, but can anyone explain why not Map<Object, Map> and Map<Object, Collection>?

Comment: From your comment I am coming to a conclusion that  line ... extends Collection<?>>  is just useless

Comment: So what did you read about type erasure in Java? If you have a look at the short description of the tag you used you'll see "In Java, type erasure is the process where the compiler removes _all information related to type parameters and type arguments_ within a class or method when a _generic type_ is instantiated." (emphasis by me) - this means _all_ generic type information is removed here thus the type becomes `Map` only.

Comment: When we have type bounds, such things work fine: <br>public static <T extends Collection<?>>  void doSomething(T ob) {
        
    } and
    public static <T extends List<?>>  void doSomething(T ob) {
        
    } because of the bounds (the T is replaced with List and Collection, not with object)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do `? extends Collection<?>` may or may not be useful. Those generic types are a hint to the compiler only, i.e. if you'd try to pass in a `Map<Something, String>` the compiler would recognize that `String` doesn't match the `extends Collection<?>` boundary and produce an error.

Comment: Yes that works because the compiler will be able to infer the minimal type of `T` which is `Collection` in the first case and `List` in the second. That, however, works only on one level and thus `Map<?, ? extends Collection<?>>` will still result in `Map` only (you could also think of it happening twice, i.e. the first step would result in `Map<Object, Collection>` while the second would result in `Map`).

Comment: From the question rating it seems like it was kind of a very stupid question, so I would like to say "sorry" for taking time. I have read the tutorils and other post on type erasure, but sometimes formal definitions are too obsure for me to apply in real life... So thanks to all that helped me to figure this issue out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The erasure of `Map<?, ? extends Collection<?>>` is `Map<Object, Object>`

The erasure of `Map<?, ? extends Map<?, ?>>` is also `Map<Object, Object>`

To understand why, you need to understand how how the erasure of `Map` is calculated.  Basically, you take the type (`Map<K, V>`) and replace the *formal* type parameters (not the *actual* type parameters) with their respective *least upper bound* types.  In this case, the least upper bound type is `Object` for both `K` and `V`, since neither have any type constraints on them ... in the `Map` interface.

I think I might have made up the term "least upper bound type".  (Sorry)  But what I mean is the most specific type that is not a subtype of any of the possible types in the set that are allowed.

---

Another way to think of erasure is as follows.  Consider this class:

```
public class Test <T> {
    public set(T t):
}
```

Now imagine that we had to express that without using generics.  What actual type would we use in place of `T`?  In this case, it would be `Object`.

And in fact, when a generic type is mapped to a runtime type, that is *exactly* what happens!

---

But, basically, you won't be able to create overloads of a method that differ only on the type parameterization of a `Map` type.  Unless you reify the types:

```
  public class X implements Map<String, Integer> ...

  public class Y implements Map<String, Double> ...

  public static String doSomething(X map) {
     ...
  }

  public static String doSomething(Y map) {
     ...
  }
```

.... which is ugly, to say the least.

Solution: use different method names instead of trying to overload the same name.

Comment: Thanks, that clears the issue more than a quotes like "In Java, type erasure is the process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method when a generic type is instantiated". I read this, but I was misled that bounding will somewhat influence the inference which method to use .

Comment: Such cases I have seen in the tutorial on generics. But when we have bounded type e.g. <T extends Serializable>. Will the T be Serializable?

Comment: Analogy with such cases confused me (I thought that such type of erasure would occur if I used bounded wildcards).

Comment: @KonstantinK - Actually, your real source of confusion is that you are considering the actual type parameters rather than the formal type parameters.

Comment: If simple, formal parameters are those that I pass in method signature, actual - those that I pass in code when calling, right?  My main fault is that I didn't fully understand how the erasure worked, like Thomas specified in his comment.

Comment: Yes, last seems ugly, better to have different methods.

Comment: I meant two differently named methods in class, not language. All languages are good unless you misuse them.

Comment: Sorry.  I misunderstood.

Comment: The erasure of these parameter types is just `Map`. It doesn’t matter which type parameters or bounds you use, there can be only one method with this name and a single parameter of type `Map`, regardless of whether or how the `Map` has been parameterized. The simplest fix is to give both methods a different name, perhaps more meaningful than “`doSomething`”.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot overload a method where the formal parameter types of each overload erase to the same raw type.

In your code, both method have the same signature after type erasure:

```
public static String doSomething(Map map);
```

To solve your problem, you can use just two different method names instead of overloading the method.

Comment: So I cannot in any way figure out whether the collection is nested or not at compile type without something like instanceof?

Comment: @KonstantinK how would you call that anyways? The compiler would have to make the distinction at compile time so you can as well just call a different method (e.g. with a different name or in a different class).

Comment: At compile type I have type Map<String, List<Double>> or Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>. I have tried to distinguish between such on compile-time with single method. Of course, I had a solution of processing them both with different methods, but since the action was similiar on both types, I decided that it would be good if I had one overloaded method.